# wxPython - Possible to overwrite System Default Font?

Tags: fonts, wxpython

I am using wxPython for my GUI. On windows PCs using "Segoe UI" as default Font everything is looking good. A collegue of me, working in china, has a different system default font. I dont know how its called but it is messing with spaces in my GUI. 
I tried to fix most of them, but also ListCtrls and so on use the chinese font.

So i search for a way to overwrite the default font my wx Application is using to prevent me from changing it for each widget.

i tried to overwrite it like this:

```
    self.SetFont(wx.Font(9, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False,'Segoe UI'))
```

but this is working mainly with panels and not with ListCtrls.

I can get the default font like this:

```
import wx

    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "", size=(600,300))


            fnt = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)

            wx.SystemSettings.
            print(fnt.GetFaceName())


    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

But i cant change it in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may not be optimal, you can set the font of the/all `ListCtrl` separately, with a simple `SetFont`.

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Font")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.MODERN, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL, faceName='Linux Libertine')
        self.index = 0
        self.text = "Timbuktoo"
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(750,350),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        #panel.SetFont(font)
        self.list_ctrl.SetFont(font)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject', width=100)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due', width=150)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=300)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 1, "22/05/2020")
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 2, self.text)
        self.index += 1
        self.text = self.text+"1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define a font with:

```
self.font=wx.Font(16, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, "Arial")
```

You can set different fonts for different occasion. For example when you want to make it bigger or bold etc.

You then can set the font on all the widgets you have:

```
 self.NameOfDatabase=wx.StaticText(self.somepanel,-1)
 self.NameOfDatabase.SetLabel('Sometext')
 self.NameOfDatabase.SetFont(self.font)
```

To change the font in the listctrl widget you have to change the font from every item. with

```
 SetItemFont(self, item, font)
```

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ListCtrl.html#wx.ListCtrl.SetItemFont

Answer (score 0):

Changing the panel's font should work. Are you sure that your listCtrl is a child of the panel?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss panel.SetFont(). Here is an example code to change the overall wxPython font.

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
self.top_panel = wx.Panel(self)
self.top_panel.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, 'Consolas'))
```